# What is a Past Event Horizon?

Tags: general-relativity, event-horizon, causality, white-holes

I've recently been informed about a few things from a reliable source:

1) Wormholes can't form via gravitational collapse

2) The event horizons in an ER bridge can't collide

I understand what a future event horizon is by realizing that once reaching any point on its "surface" there is no longer any trajectory but inward and thus all futures point inward. I understand this via the gravitational collapse mechanism. I don't understand how a past event horizon could form (and therefore what it is). I would very much appreciate answers that take the perspective of the past event horizon (without referring to black holes at all - to make it very clear)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A past event horizon would be a surface such that one could only pass it on past-directed curves. Inside it, anything within would be forced out, and then once past the horizon, could not enter again. This object is a so-called 'white hole', the opposite of a black hole. We know of no physical processes that could create such an object and none have ever been observed, save for one [contended event](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GRB_060614).

Comment: thank you for the great link. 102 seconds burst with no supernova - so mysterious! I was out walking at night once when I saw something like a plasma burst in the sky but it was maximum 1-2 seconds. Quite large though. I get the part that anything inside a "white-hole" would be forced out but by what - anti-gravity? I don't get immediately what *past-directed curves* are. Do you mean curves caused by past events? I guess such objects would be very difficult to observe since no information can enter them and no probing by measurement as such.

Comment: A past directed curve is a path in spacetime that is pointed towards the past. Essentially, there is no path you can take to enter the blackhole while going towards the future (along future directed curves, the only curves we can travel along). You could observe them by the matter and radiation they expulse.